# Is there a way to debug console programs from the command-prompt?

Tags: debugging, methods, console, command-prompt

At the moment, I’m writing a small console program. It is small enough that I have not bothered to use an IDE, so I’m just using Notepad2 and `cl.exe` to edit and build the program, and the command-prompt to run and test it.

This works just fine for the most part (don’t freak out, but I’m actually using a bit of *“`printf` debugging”* here and there). Unfortunately certain problems are not quite as easy to fix. For example, a pointer/array problem can cause the program to crash.

I know about—and have—Visual Studio, Ollydbg, Windbg, etc. but those are all fancy, schmancy graphical IDEs and debuggers that are too cumbersome to fire up for what usually amounts to a five-second check before going back to the editor. My edit-compile-test cycle is often as low as 10-15 seconds, so such debuggers become an unacceptable bottleneck.

I’m trying to find out if there is a fast and easy method to debug a console application from the command-prompt. Is there a modern text-mode debugger? (Obviously `debug` isn’t going to be of much use.) Is there some other way—TSR‽—to view values, catch exceptions, or set breakpoints and step through a program?

Comment: Don't some of the unix editors support this. I remember using a similar approach in a lab in school. After going through that experience I am on the other side and prefer VS :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need ntsd (part of the same package as WinDbg, shares all comands) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Also using free Visual Studio Express may make search for debugging advices easier...

Comment: NTSD looks promising. I just wish it would run in the current console instead of popping open a separate one which can’t be piped into `more`. As for VS, like I said, I’ve already got (and older version of) that and it is not useful for this purpose.